# Magento 2 : "My billing and shipping address are the same" checkbox remain unchecked

Tags: checkout, magento2.3, payment-methods, billing-address, enable-disable

I have created a custom extension for product based cash on delivery. 
I have followed the below link for creating the extension.

[Disable payment method programmatically in Magento2](https://webkul.com/blog/disable-payment-method-programmatically-magento2/)

Everything works fine,except the billing address checkbox.

If the condition is false, then the COD method is not available and the "My billing and shipping address are the same" checkbox remains checked.

If the condition is true, then the COD method is available. But the  "My billing and shipping address are the same" checkbox will be unchecked.

I am using Magento 2.3.2.

How can I resolve this?